# sorting elements in the list in python

Tags: python-2.7

suppose the list is like this

```
l = [("Texas","city1"), ("Texas","city2"), ("Texas","city3"), ("Texas","city4"), ("Texas","city5"),
("Georgia","city6"), ("Georgia","city9"), ("Georgia","city10"),
("Alabama","city7"), ("Alabama","city8")]
```

This list will have a unique state names.

Now what i need two things to be done with this list.

1) sorting based on states first and cities second. say after sorting based on states first and cities second the list looks like this

```
l = [("Georgia","city6"),("Georgia","city9"),("Georgia","city10"),("Texas","city1"), ("Texas","city2"), ("Texas","city3"), ("Texas","city4"), ("Texas","city5"),("Alabama","city7"), ("Alabama","city8")]
```

2) after this step i need the states to be alphabetized with their corresponding cities. Say i need like below format finally.

```
l = [("Alabama","city7"), ("Alabama","city8"),("Georgia","city6"),("Georgia","city9"),("Georgia","city10"),("Texas","city1"), ("Texas","city2"), ("Texas","city3"), ("Texas","city4"), ("Texas","city5")]
```

sorted(lsNearCities, key=operator.itemgetter(0,1)) --> I assume this would sort based on states first and then cities second. And after that how should i accomplish the list which i needed using python. Please help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
l = [("Texas","city1"), ("Texas","city2"), ("Texas","city3"), ("Texas","city4"), ("Texas","city5"),("Georgia","city6"), ("Georgia","city9"), ("Georgia","city10"),("Alabama","city7"), ("Alabama","city8")]

def cmp(x,y):
    if x[0]<y[0]:
        return -1
    elif x[0]>y[0]:
        return 1
    elif x[1]<y[1]:
        return -1
    elif x[1]>y[1]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

l.sort(cmp)
print l
```

By the way, this is the default sorting so if you don't want to do a different sort then you can just simply do:

```
l.sort()
```

You can change the cmp function for different sort modes. I'm not sure what you mean by "alphabetizing"?

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.                                               My code is here                                                                        lsNearCities = []                                                                      state_and_cities = str(nearCity)  + "," + str(state)
lsNearCities.append(state_and_cities)
sorted(lsNearCities, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0)). What i should add after this? please give me a snippet as per my code, since am new to python.

Comment: lsNearCities = [('Abbeville','SC'), ('Easley','SC'), ('Baxter','TN'), ('Ducktown','TN'), ('Sylva','NC'),('Rutherfordton','NC'), ('Covington','GA'), ('Clarkston','GA'),('Maylene','AL'), ('Hatton','AL')]
def cmp(x,y):
 if x[0]<y[0]:
  return -1
 elif x[0]>y[0]:
  return 1
 elif x[1]<y[1]:
  return -1
 elif x[1]>y[1]:
  return 1
 else:
  return 0
lsNearCities.sort(cmp)
print lsNearCities
[('Abbeville', 'SC'), ('Baxter', 'TN'), ('Clarkston', 'GA'), ('Covington', 'GA'), ('Ducktown', 'TN'), ('Easley', 'SC'), ('Hatton', 'AL'), ('Maylene', 'AL'), ('Rutherfordton', 'NC'), ('Sylva', 'NC')]

Comment: I tried your function and got the output as ahown above. What i want is lsNearCities = [('Hatton', 'AL'),('Maylene', 'AL'),('Clarkston', 'GA'),('Covington', 'GA'), ('Rutherfordton', 'NC'), ('Sylva', 'NC'),('Abbeville', 'SC'),('Easley', 'SC'),('Baxter', 'TN'), ('Ducktown', 'TN')]